# Is my RX 580 defective or has been tampered with?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, bios, gpu, flash

So some time ago I **purchased a used RX 580 4GB** to have as a temporary gaming GPU.

All seemed fine on paper, but it ended up with me having to open up my gpu, **change the thermal paste**, and even **flash the BIOS** since it was acting very strange and it's config wasn't regular from what I remember.

After all of that work, the gpu ran fine but **my 2nd monitor (DVI) is green** and only goes away for a short period of time when I completely remove the GPU from the device manager but it always comes back.
Now I have a problem where I try to install drivers and it goes through but I get an error 1603.
**This morning it started to freeze on me** while idle on windows but that stopped after I reinstalled the drivers and got the error of course.

Now it is ramping up to **3000RPM+ on more than 75C**

I'm just wondering what I can do other than what I've already done.
Still need this GPU till the end of the year and I don't want to crazy while I don't hear anything else other than it ramping up like a jet engine.

Note: if I had automatic fan curves on the **AMD adrenaline** software, it never wanted to calm down with the fans until it was 100% cool. So it was **always on 2400-3000RPM** so I set a fan curve on MSI Afterburner for now.

Edit:

- Everything was regular and okay yesterday so this happening from yesterday night to today morning is really odd.

Comment: Sounds like it had a thermal problem

Comment: @Ramhound It did when I got it and it looked horrible but as I said I changed it and now everything is happening as described above.

Comment: “Now it is ramping up to 3000RPM+ on more than 75C” - This is the reason I indicated you have a thermal problem

Comment: @Ramhound But I don't understand it tho. I changed the paste like a month ago. And at the time I changed it, it was all good and literally yesterday it was all good.

Comment: Sounds like the thermal paste needs changing again. Use good quality paste/pads and make sure that voltage regulators are also well cooled. It is entirely possible that the card was run into the ground by crypto currency mining and will continue to exhibit issues.

Comment: @Jan - A thermal problem is more likely than the card being tampered with, the problems you describe, are the reason used cards a bad idea

Comment: @Mokubai Any to recommend? And I am not very familiar with hands on GPU components and functionality as I probably should be as well.

Comment: It's entirely possible that movement has broken the seal on the paste you applied making it useless again, particularly if the heatsink isn't 100% solidly mounted, or if the card is slightly warped by age or heat or other issues. It's impossible to know why a used card was sold on, it might have been perfect, or it might be that they knew it was dying and wanted to make a buck before it was too late and you were the unlucky recipient.

Comment: @Mokubai I noticed that the thermal pads weren't all intact anymore the first time I opened it up. Some looked a bit ripped. So guessing by what you said I should change both the pads and the paste?

Comment: Yes. you should replace everything as a set. If the pads are no longer doing their job then other parts of the card will be overheating. Pads should have a certain softness to them which lets them mould to the components and they dry out over time. If you broke their seal and the heatsink doesn't 100% compress them exactly the same then they are essentially useless. I don't have any recommendations because there are too many types and you would have to find ones that look mostly similar to what you have but with thickness that allows for slight compression.

Comment: @Mokubai One more question tho, since it's a thermal issue, that would affect the idle temps too or no? Because on idle windows it sits on max 50C

Comment: It can affect idle temperatures, but graphics cards have aggressive power saving and variable fan speeds. The idle temperature might well be the same as a better card, but with the fan running slightly faster.